# Linux Kernel Programming - Module 2 unable to get symbols exported by Module 1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, symbols

I have a Linux kernel module **M1** which exports a symbol **S1**. When I *insmod M1.ko*, I can see **S1** in */proc/kallsyms*. I use **S1** in another kernel module **M2**. When I compile and insert module **M2**, I get message in *dmesg* saying *"Unknown symbol in module S1".*

I am stumped. Can someone please tell me what is going wrong? I am using Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: Can you post all EXPORT_SYMBOL* code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the symbol really exported?  If you ask for a modinfo dump of the symbols from M1, is it there?

Comment: my mistake. Problem due to programming error. Thanks for your inputs ppl. :) –